# Checking every element of two dimensional array is sorted in ascending order or not

Tags: arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Actually I was trying to make a number puzzle game in which you will have to move the shuffled numbers into the blank space and eventually arrange all 15 numbers in ascending order. I am able to play and order all the numbers of the game, but when it comes to checking whether all the numbers are sorted in ascending order i.e from 1 to 15, I don't get the required results. This is the last part of game where the checking is done and result is announced. I tried a lot, and eventually I ended up typing stupid if else conditions. 
I don't want ready made code, a small hint or procedure will be appreciated.

```
/*My two dimensional array is of 4 * 4 dimension.
Initially to test whether all the elements are sorted in ascending order or 
not
I took a casual approach, the same we use in for one dimensional array.*/

for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) //row = 4
{
    for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) // col = 4
    {
        int k = j + 1;
        if(k != 4)
        {
            if(array[i][j] < array[i][k])
                continue;
        }
    }
}

/*But this above code isn't the right code because it checks whether each 
 and every row is correctly sorted or not
 So even if my output is 
 1 2 3 4
 5 6 7 8
 9 10 13 14
 11 12 15 _ 
 it will say game completed or you have won whereas my expected output was 
 this 
 1 2 3 4
 5 6 7 8
 9 10 11 12
 13 14 15 _  ***UNDERSCORE SIGN IS MEANT FOR BLANK SPACE */`
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Can you please tell us something more? What language are we talking about here? And can you show us part of your code you have problem with?

Comment: Sorry for not uploading code. Here it is! @rsm

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using VB then this will be pseudo-code:

```vb
Function ArrayIsOrdered(arr(,) As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim xSize = arr.GetUpperBound(0)
    Dim ySize = arr.GetUpperBound(1)

    ' set a temporary variable to the lowest possible value
    Dim x = Integer.MinValue

    ' iterate over the array
    For j = 0 To ySize
        For i = 0 To xSize
            ' if this value is less than the previous value
            ' then the array is not in order
            If arr(i, j) < x Then
                Return False
            End If
            ' save this value for the next comparison
            x = arr(i, j)
        Next
    Next

    ' everything must have been in order
    Return True

End Function
```

Lines starting with an apostrophe are comments.

You need to be sure which array dimensions you're using for across and down.

If you have a magic value for an unoccupied square then you'll need to ignore a cell with that value, of course.